# SwipeRefreshLayout refresh animation doesn't stop, though I set swipeView.setRefreshing(false)

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I found some answers like

[SwipeRefreshLayout refresh animation doesn't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506985/swiperefreshlayout-refresh-animation-doesnt-stop/30508938)

plus some other Q&A, but till now I have not found my solution, Even I can not understand the problem.

Actually the class is pageAdapter

My Code is

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    View listView = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_common_list, container, false);
    swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) listView.findViewById(R.id.nfs);
    swipeView.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,
            R.color.colorAccent,
            R.color.yes,
            R.color.no);
    swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d("SwipeView","Refrehing");
                            swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
                            Log.d("SwipeView ",swipeView.isRefreshing()+"");
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                }


            });
}
```

and my **fragment_common_list** view is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/nfs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tab_height">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commonList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: What is `listview` inthis code: `swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) listView.findViewById(R.id.nfs);`?

Comment: @Umang Burman Actually the class is extended PageAdapter, not an activity or fragment.
I have modified the code. listview is inflated from fragment_common_list.xml file

Comment: Are ypu using PagerAdapter from like Paging Library? Can you post your entire code of java please?

Comment: where you calling **swipeView.setRefreshing(true);** share that code. Usually we make it **TRUE** on onRefresh method and then make it **FALSE** once loading of item is done. Please share the complete code.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma My code was like 
                      @ Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
                                ......
                                ......
Thats also does not work. :(

Comment: As per your question, swipe refresh animation shouldn't visible until you call swipeView.setRefreshing(true). I am here trying to understand how it's visible forever for you. You must be calling somewhere swipeView.setRefreshing(true)

Comment: @Zenith I have posted code to find out the issue, if your swipe refresh keeps animating forever I would recommend you try that.

Comment: Use setRefreshing(false); without the handler and check whether it is going off.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Instead of:

```
swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) listView.findViewById(R.id.nfs);
```

Write:

```
swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.nfs);
```

If it's an `Activity`, declare it in `onCreate();`

If it's in `Fragment`, then declare it in `onCreateView()` with the view object.

Try it, Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually the class is extended PageAdapter, not an activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> Note : This post is about to understand the issue so I'm not expecting
>   to get any vote up/down, i'll remove once question get clarified.

Change your code like below and let me know if you still have the same issue.

```
swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
        loadItems();
    }
});


private void loadItems() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Till now not working. I just copied and replace your code :(

Comment: Where else you calling this method **swipeView.setRefreshing(true)**. Issue is swipe refresh animation keeps running forever right?

Comment: @Zenith updated answer to make swipe refresh invisible swipeView.setRefreshing(false); at the beginning. Also for testing purpose make sure that you are not calling swipeView.setRefreshing(true); anywhere other than onRefresh